# mysqlimport won't load records to a table created with LIKE statement

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I have some mysql table `products`, I use [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) to load data to it from CSV file. I created another table copy_products using the following command: `CREATE TABLE copy_products LIKE products;`

Now when I try to load data to copy_products using mysqlimport, it gives the same message like the old one: `"db.copy_products: Records: 1000  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0"` which indicates that all rows in the CSV file are inserted (as I understand). However the table is empty and has no records! So any clue here ? Are tables created using LIKE statement special in some way?

Comment: Are you inside of a transaction? Are you sure you're connected to the correct database?

Comment: no I'm not inside a transaction, and yes I'm sure I'm connected to the correct database.

Comment: If it says that data was inserted and it wasn't, then those are the two most common problems. If you drop the table can you still insert data into it? Tables created with `LIKE` are ordinary tables once the operation is complete, there's absolutely nothing special about them.

Comment: maybe "db.copy_products: Records: 1000 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 0 Warnings: 0" doesn't really mean that data was inserted ?

Comment: That does suggest that 1000 records were inserted with no warnings, no deletions and no skips. It's worth testing that theory, though. I usually use CSV import and `LOAD DATA INFILE` directly, mind you.

Comment: It is solved and I don't know how, I tried to follow your advice, dropped the table and then run mysqlimport and it worked! Then using the same command (use db) again, I found that the table is there and it has data. I don't know what happened but I'm pleased that it is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need after create the clone  of table. You need to insert the records in the new table as the following:

```
> CREATE TABLE copy_products LIKE products;
> INSERT INTO copy_products SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY id;
```

If You want to make it in one statement, try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE copy_products SELECT * FROM products group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use mysqlimport not normal insertion, and the problem is solved now :)

Comment: @LoaiGhoraba you can answer on the question to share your info :)